# Chrome does not update or render unless mouse moves

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have recently been having this rendering problem in Chrome :

When I click on a button or do something that updates the GUI, nothing happens until I wiggle my mouse around. It is almost as if my mouse-click-event is stuck in some kind of queue and only gets shaken out of this queue if I wiggle my mouse or do some other kind of event.

This is starting to drive me nuts. Any idea what this is?

Comment: Seems to be a bug with graphic acceleration, can you try to disable it?

Comment: I have the same problem (but I'm using a touchpad). I might scroll, but Chrome does not render until I move the cursor. Very annoying. I'm on a System 76 laptop with Pop_os! Linux and Nvidia graphics turned on. I disabled "GPU rasterization" in about:flags, but that didn't help.